# Two sound fades in a single AVPlayerItem

Tags: ios, audio, fadein, fadeout, avplayer

Thanks to a [stackoverflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715148/why-isnt-my-avplayer-volume-fading-out) I am able to fade one AVPlayerTrack in or out. But I can't find a way to do both on a single track.

This is what I am trying to use:

```
-(void)fadeOutVolume
{
    AVPlayerItem *myAVPlayerItem = self.songPlayer.currentItem;

    AVAsset *myAVAsset = myAVPlayerItem.asset;
    NSArray *audioTracks = [myAVAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

    NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {

       AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams = 
        [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:track];

       CMTime fadeDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5, 600);
       CMTime fadeOutStartTime = 
         CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(myAVPlayerItem.duration)-5, 600);
       CMTime fadeInStartTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 600);


       [audioInputParams setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:1.0 
                                           toEndVolume:0 
                      timeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(fadeOutStartTime, fadeDuration)];

       AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams2 = 
        [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:track];

       [audioInputParams2 setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:0.0 
                                           toEndVolume:1.0  
                        timeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(fadeInStartTime, fadeDuration)];


        [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
        [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams2];

    }

    AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];

    [audioMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];
    [myAVPlayerItem setAudioMix:audioMix];

}
```

This works if I comment `[allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];` or the other line. But I can't have the two input params at the same time.

Comment: `setVolumeRampFromStartVolume` can only be set once. Try to find a different param setting.

Comment: I thought so :/. I can't add two different input parameters that set the volume ramp? :/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the problem. I don't need two audioInputParams. In fact, it seems like they override somehow.

If I delete the new audioInputParam and do the two set ramps it all works well. Actually this is kinda missleading. SetRamp it seems like is going to override and the "addObject" is the one that overrides. I ended up with this code in the for part:

```
AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams = 
        [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:track];


CMTime fadeDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5, 600);
CMTime fadeOutStartTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(myAVPlayerItem.duration)-5, 600);
CMTime fadeInStartTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 600);

[audioInputParams setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:1.0 toEndVolume:0 timeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(fadeOutStartTime, fadeDuration)];

[audioInputParams setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:0.0 toEndVolume:1.0 timeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(fadeInStartTime, fadeDuration)];

[allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
```

Thanks @Mundi for the attempt to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can only set the start volume ramp once. This is sort of logical, right?

If you want to change the volume again later, use

```
setVolume:atTime:
```

> This method adds a volume ramp starting at time. This volume setting remains in effect until the end of the track unless you set a different volume level to start at a later time.

**EDIT:**

Maybe this answer is not entirely correct. There is nothing in the docs that would indicate this restriction.

But I noticed that you iterate through the tracks and set the `fadeOutStratTime` based on `myAVPlayerItem` - perhaps there is a logic mistake leading to the error.

Comment: With that solution it all becomes so messy. I need a timer that sets up in a delta interval that will change the volume from 0 to 1 in alfa seconds. Ramps are so much cleaner solution. Is this the only way ?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong. I looked at the docs and I am not really sure anymore why it does not work. Do you have a crash message? Also, see my edit above for another idea.

Comment: I don't have any crash message. Adittionally, the fade out and the fade in work individually. If I comment one of the lines     `[allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];` the other works. Both work individually. That is why is odd :/.

Comment: I have found the issue. Just a confusion of the api names that led me to think I couldn't do two setRamps. Thanks for the help @Mundi ;)