# Need fading effect while playing music

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, ios8

In my application, I'm using both iPod Player for playing background music(Music App) and AvAudioPlayer for playing the songs from URL's. I want to put fading effect for the songs while switching between these players. I tried the way by decreasing the volume of one player and increasing the other, but it did not give me the fading effect. Can anyone help me how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance

This is my code

```
- (IBAction)play:(id)sender
{
    timerCount = 0;
    playAndPauseTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(playTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)playTimer
{
    MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

    if(timerCount < 10) {
        timerCount++;

        float volume = musicPlayer.volume;
        if(volume>0) {
            volume = musicPlayer.volume-0.02f;
            [musicPlayer setVolume:volume];
        }
    } else {
        [playAndPauseTimer invalidate];
        [musicPlayer setVolume:initialVolume];
        [audioplayer play];
        pauseButton.hidden = NO;
        startButton.hidden = YES;
    }
}

- (IBAction)pause:(id)sender
{
    //[self pauseTimer];
    timerCount=0;
    playAndPauseTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(pauseTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)pauseTimer
{
    MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

    if(timerCount < 10) {
        timerCount++;

        float volume = musicPlayer.volume;
        if(volume > 0){
            volume = musicPlayer.volume-0.02f;
            [musicPlayer setVolume:volume];
        }
    } else {
        [playAndPauseTimer invalidate];
        [audioplayer pause];
        [musicPlayer setVolume:initialVolume];
        pauseButton.hidden = YES;
        startButton.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: What effect did it give with your method? Also, could you show your code for the volume stuff?

Comment: I added my code. Could you look in to that and suggest me @Fogmeister

Comment: Good, I need one too.

Comment: Have you looked at this thread: [Volume fade out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715148/why-isnt-my-avplayer-volume-fading-out).
This might also help you figure this out: [Overlapping Audio Tracks](http://www.postblog.me/2012/03/playing-multiple-overlapping-audio-tracks-in-background/)